# Determine how long video has played?

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I use `cordova` to develop a app to show video clips and using this https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer plugin to show video in my application.

My requirement is, measure how long has user seen every clip so that I can change java code of plugin.

Here is the code of plug-in which play the video:

```
 intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
 this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

I can find the time of when video has started playing. What I don't know is how to find the time of when video has stopped playing or when user tapped back button.

Another problem is I don't know how to send this start and end time of video to the html page to display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

To detect when back key pressed you can use [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()).

To detect when video has you can use [onPause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()).

To detect when intent finished [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

For full documentation visit [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#lfields)

Comment: i added this  :  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   webView.addJavascriptInterface(mActivity, "callBack");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("javascript: sayHello('yourName'));
} but sayhello function dosen't raise

Comment: @MHF what do you got there?

Comment: in helloworld function in java script i only change the text of div for test : <script>
 
 function sayHello(name) {
 
   $(".tt").html(name);
  }

 </script>